# Call contract function from another

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I want to know what make the function below called successfully using web3js and throw **" Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"** when I call it from another smart contract.

```
function addVacancy(address sender, bytes32 vacancyId, uint256 incentive) public  {

        Vacancy vacancy = vacancies[vacancyId];
        vacancy.incentive = incentive;
        vacancy.owner = sender;

        emit NewVacancy(vacancyId, incentive, sender );
    }
```

from another smart contract:

```
function helpMe () public {
   //this throw an error
firstContract.addVacancy(_sender, vacancyId, _value);
}
```

**EDIT :** helpMe() is receiveApproval()

the methode helpMe () is inside the serviceContract:

```
contract ServiceContract {
  FirstContract firstContract;
  address owner;

  constructor (address _firstContract,
        address _endorserContract) {
        firstContract = FirstContract(_firstContract);
        owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function receiveApproval(address _sender, uint256 _value,
        address _tokenContract, bytes data) public {

       bytes32 vacancyId = keccak256(data);
            // this cauz the error
            firstContract.addVacancy(_sender, vacancyId, _value);
}
```

Comment: Let's see the whole thing, including the method of instantiating `firstContract`.

Comment: I made an EDIT.

Comment: You've inspired a question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51889/why-does-this-work-with-solidity-0-4-21-but-not-0-4-22

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are compiling with byzantium expectations (0.4.22 or higher) and then trying to run it on a node (and chain) that doesn't support byzantium.

You'll get a runtime error when the expected parameters are not returned. This post describes the new return values and problem others are having with common contracts. https://medium.com/@chris_77367/explaining-unexpected-reverts-starting-with-solidity-0-4-22-3ada6e82308c

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using truffle for migration and compile, how can I choose the compiler version ?

Comment: `$ truffle version` will reveal. Each version of truffle comes with/dictates the solc version included. Upgrade truffle, if needed, to help align everything.