# Why does this work with Solidity 0.4.21 but not 0.4.22?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, compiler

I have this simple set of contracts.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract FirstContract {

  bool public isTrue = true;

  function sayHello() public pure returns(bool) {
      return true;
  }

}

contract ServiceContract {

  FirstContract firstContract;

  function ServiceContract (address _firstContract) public {
    firstContract = FirstContract(_firstContract);
  }

  function confirmFirstContract() public view returns(bool) {
      bool x = firstContract.isTrue();
      return x;
  }

  function sayHi() public view returns(bool) {
      bool y = firstContract.sayHello();
      return y;
  }

}
```

When this is compiled and deployed in the correct sequence using 0.4.21, `confirmFirstContract()` and `sayHi()` return `true` as expected.

When the compiler is changed to 0.4.22 the same function returns an "invalid opcode".

Why would that be?

I found this blog that suggests some hints. https://medium.com/@chris_77367/explaining-unexpected-reverts-starting-with-solidity-0-4-22-3ada6e82308c

Thanks!

Comment: This code works fine for me on Remix with `0.4.22+commit.4cb486ee.Emscripten.clang`. The hint in the article you link to would suggest that perhaps `firstContract` doesn't hold the right address. If you could provide more details about how to reproduce the error, I'd be happy to try further.

Comment: Are you testing against ganache, geth or some other client? Does it have byzantinum fork enabled?

Comment: `function ServiceContract` is a "regular" function, not a constructor. Either change it to `constructor`, or call it explicitly from your off-chain code before you call `function confirmFirstContract`. This function returns "invalid opcode" because the `firstContract` variable has not been initialized to point to a deployed `FirstContract` instance (i.e., it still points to address 0).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, solc 0.4.21 warns about deprecated constructor syntax but still treats it as a constructor function, whereas newer versions of solc treat it is a normal function. This should explain the problem that you're experiencing.

Comment: By the way, as you might have already realized, your "constructor" now yields a security breach in your contract, since it's a public function which anyone can invoke. I know of at least one company who had all their money drained out during their ICO, because of a similar scenario (in their case, it was before the `constructor` keyword had been introduced - they decided to rename the contract, but forgot to rename the constructor).

Comment: The cause might be that the new version of solidity compiler uses `returndatasize` opcode and you are running against an implementation that doesn't have byzantinum fork enabled. https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/4116.